# Difference in typesetting of given examples

Tags: math-mode, matlab

Consider the following two examples, they produce same output

Do they follow different typesettings?

Only the first is producing a output in Matlab not second, can someone hint me, why?

1.`\left[{\matrix{2 \cr 1 \cr 4 \cr}}\right]`

2.`\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}`

Thanks

Comment: The first version is plain TeX syntax, the second `LaTeX`. I don't have `matlab`, so can't say why the second does not work

Comment: And the second one needs `amsmath` package.

Comment: The output is not identical - the second version sets the brackets closer to the content.

Comment: This question is about using TeX from within MATLAB. In my opinion, it's off-topic, for similar reasons why [questions about MathJax are off-topic on the site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version

`$left[{\matrix{2 \cr 1 \cr 4 \cr}}\right]$`

is pure plain TeX and typesets a matrix

whereas

`$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$` is using the `bmatrix` environment, which is `LaTeX` accordingly then.

It requires either `amsmath` or `mathtools` package. Most probably, `matlab` does not use those packages by default.

Two small examples:

`plainmatrix.tex` -- use `pdftex` or `tex` to compile

```
This a matrix with square brackets:


$\left[{\matrix{2 \cr 1 \cr 4 \cr}}\right]$

\bye
```

`latexmatrix.tex` -- use `latex` or `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
This a matrix with square brackets using \LaTeXe:

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Due to definitions in `amsmath` you can't use `\matrix` any longer in a document that includes `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) directly.